# binary search algorithm not working

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to implement a binary search and somehow my function doesn't return the value wanted

```
import math
def binarySearch(a, l, r, v): 
    if l >= r:
        return -1
    mid = math.floor((l + r)/ 2)

    if a[mid] == v:
        return mid
    elif(v < mid):
        binarySearch(a,mid+1,r,v)
    else:
        binarySearch(a,l,mid-1,v)

a = [1,2,5,8,23,67,345]

print(binarySearch(a,0,6,5));
```

It keeps returning `-1` Can someone shed a light where I went wrong?

Comment: Don't you need to `return` the result from your recursive calls?

Comment: [bisect.bisect_left](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) exists in the standard library for performing a binary search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have return in elif statement so your function can return only -1

```
import math
def binarySearch(a, l, r, v): 
    if l > r:
        return -1
    mid = math.floor((l + r)/ 2)

    if a[mid] == v:
        return mid
    elif(v < a[mid]):
        return binarySearch(a,l,mid-1,v)
    else:
        return binarySearch(a,mid+1,r,v)
```

Comment: That's not true. If `a[mid] == v` is false, the execution hits the end of the function after returning from the recursive calls and will return `None`.

Comment: Nope, I still get -1

Comment: I've edited the code, there was another mistake: if v < mid then you should be searching for result in left part in your case you do the opposite: you search in right side.

Comment: The mistake wasn't only the wrong way of the comparison (less than vs. greater than), but you need to check the array value, not the index: `elif v < a[mid]:`

Comment: He had mistake in comparison too.

Comment: There's still one error left: When the upper bound is inclusive, the empty range corresounds to the condition `l > r`. A single-element range has ´l == r`, so the codition ´l >= r` will miss out on every second element.

Comment: So yes 4th mistake :D it should be `l > r`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
    if (r>=l)
    {
        int mid = l + (r - l)/2;

        if (arr[mid] == x)
           return mid;

        if (arr[mid] > x)
           return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);

        return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
    }

    return -1;
}
```